# BLDC motor erroneous running with digital potentiometer

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, potentiometer

I am using this digital potentiometer http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/31917.pdf to control a BLDC motor with Arduino Mega. When I am running the below code, the motor runs at the lowest speed when I am setting **i = 0** in **forward()** function.

```
const int CS = 10;
const int INC = 9;
const int UD = 8;

void setup() {
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(INC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(UD, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(UD, HIGH);
}

void forward() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10) {
    setResistance(i);
    delay(10);
  }
}

void loop() {
  forward();
}

void setResistance(int percent) {
  digitalWrite(UD, LOW);
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    digitalWrite(INC, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
  }

  digitalWrite(UD, HIGH);
  for (int i = 0; i < percent; i++) {
    digitalWrite(INC, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(INC, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
  }

  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);
}
```

The problem is when I set the value of **i in the forward() function** to 70 or 80 the motor runs sometimes at a much faster speed but other times when I upload the code with the 70/80/any value other than 0, the motor doesn't move at all. When **i** is set to 0, the motor runs every time at a super slow speed but for other values it sometimes moves at a faster speed, other times it doesn't move at all.

I am not sure what is causing this issue. Please help.

Comment: it is difficult to guess the information about the motor and about how it is connected to the arduino

Comment: BLDC describes a family of motors, it is (Brushless Direct current) motor. Some have the sensors internal, some supply communication signals, some supply just phase etc.  Anything at this point would be a SWAG until more information is supplied.